# c programming adjacency matrices paths

Tags: c, matrix, path, adjacency-matrix

How do I find if there is a path from index1 to index2 in given adjacency matrix?
Do I need to use recursion?

This is my code:

```
int path(int adj_mat[][N], int*pindex1, int *pindex2)
{       
  int i=0;       //column
  int yes=0;     //flag
  int j;      
  for(i;i<N;i++)
  {
      if(adj_mat[i][*pindex2-1]==1)
      {
          if(i==*pindex1-1)
              yes=1;
          for(j=i-1; j<0;--j)
          {
              if(adj_mat[j][i]==1)
                  if(j==*pindex1-1)
                      yes=1;
          }                 
      }
  }

  return yes;
}
```

Comment: I can't think of an algorithm that *needs* recursion, but there are some where recursion helps. You don't *need* to use recursion at all. </pedant>

Answer (score -1):

I think your adjacency matrix got `0` and `1` as values. In your case `0` means that no path exist between `index1` and `index2` and `1` means that it exists.

so for a given matrix like this:

```
 0 | 0 | 0
-----------
 0 | 1 | 0
-----------
 0 | 0 | 0
```

there would only exist one path from `index1 = 1` to `index2 = 1`:

```
matrix[1][1] = 1 => a path exists
matrix[0][1] = 0 => a path does not exist
```

So you just need to return the content and check it...:

```
return adj_mat[*pindex1][*pindex2];
```

Comment: The adjacency matrix only tells you if 2 vertices are adjacent, not if there is a path between them.